# Force redirecting after i18n on symfony get messy for error page or dev toolkit

Tags: php, symfony

I have a website which uses Symfony 5 to run the backend of the application. This website was exclusively in english. Now, we want to internationalize (i18n) it. Sadly, people might have shared some pages, and we want to force the redirection of the new URL version. For example:

- before: /page-url
- now: /en/page-url

I am using this configuration for the homepage:

```yaml
# /config/routes/annotations.yaml
home_fallback:
    path: /
    controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController::urlRedirectAction
    defaults:
        path: '/%default_locale%'
        permanent: true
```

And for the other pages I am using this event subscriber:

```php
<?php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'en')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        // if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) return;
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $locale = $request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale);
            $request->setLocale($locale);
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse('/' . $locale . '/' . ltrim($request->getRequestUri(), '/')));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 20]],
        ];
    }
}
```

But when I have error 404 (when I force it, e. g. /dzqdzqdzq) my URL get messy like that *127.0.0.1:8000/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/dzqdzqdzq*

I think the redirection loop is repeating because the '_locale' attributes is not in the Request object when there is an error 404. So I have thought to a kind of workaround like testing the number of time the request has already been redirected (but I think this is not the way to do it... :/ )

Another solution I have thought about was to create fallbacks for every previous routes I have in the `/config/routes/annotations.yaml`. I hope there is another way to do it, because I have some routes with parameters and I don't know how to reinject the parameter with annotations...

If you have questions or remarks, fell free to ask. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find out how to keep having the default routes after i18n a Symfony website!

In the `config/routes/annotations.yaml`, I have set this configuration:

```yaml
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        en: '' # don't prefix URLs for English, the default locale
        fr: '/fr'
    requirements:
        _locale: '%supported_locales%'
    defaults:
        _locale: '%default_locale%'

kernel:
    resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
    type: annotation
```

According to this section in the Symfony documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#localized-routes-i18n